# QLPreviewController can not preview any file on iOS11

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11, qlpreviewcontroller

My old app is having a problem with `QLPreviewController` on iOS11 that it suddenly can not preview any file while it worked just fine on iOS10, when I try to skip step to check if can preview the file I got below message:

> Unsupported preview item type in
>   -previewItemViewControllerClassWithStyle:; for preview item  - [FileName] #PreviewItem.

I tried to create a test app to preview a same file and it worked, quite strange. I have spent a day on this and still not find out the root cause yet. Does anyone know the answer? Thanks.

Comment: What's the file type you are trying to preview?

Comment: Hi @Raffael, I have tried common files such as pdf, txt, MS words, rtf and none worked.

Comment: If you think something's changed for the worse, it's always a good idea to file a radar in the Apple developer portal. Small demo projects help illustrate the issue.

Comment: same problem here. downloaded pdf file, but can not open this Url with QlPreview, did u solve this? ios11

Comment: Have you ever solved this?